# Ajax call to controller sending an array of objects and the method in controller is unable to parse the contents

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery, razor

Following is my partial view - Call to the controller is done using an ajax call below

```
$.ajax(url, {
            type: 'POST', 
            data: { Addresses: InboundAddresses },
            cache: false,
            crossDomain: true,
            success: function (data) {
                //Populate the form values
                // Start Dialog Code
                $myWindow = jQuery('#myDiv');
                //instantiate the dialog
                $myWindow.html(data);
                $myWindow.dialog({
                    title: 'Select an address',
                    modal: true,
                    width: 'auto'
                });
                $myWindow.show();
                $myWindow.dialog("open");
                // End Dialog Code

                $('#AddressTable').on('click', 'tr', function () {
//                    alert('You clicked row ' + ($(this).index()));
                    addAddress(InboundAddresses, Message, $(this).index())
                });
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $('#Message').val('Kaboom!!! (The call blew up...#thatsucks)');
                alert('The Dialog Box call failed...Sorry :(');
            }
        });
```

I traced the code and the call is sending the contents correctly ( Verified in fiddler ) 
Receiving method in controller does have objects but content in those objects is null. I think this is a parsing issue.

See the code for method below.

```
public PartialViewResult ShowAddresses(List<Address> Addresses)
        {
            ShowAddressViewModel viewModel = new ShowAddressViewModel();
            viewModel.Addresses = Addresses;
            viewModel.Message = "NEW";
    return PartialView("_ShowAddress", viewModel);
}
```

Comment: What does your json data look like when it's being sent?

Comment: It is a list of address objects. Each address object has address1,2 , city,state,zip

Comment: and Address has the same properties that the each json objects has? Check each property name.

Comment: I am sorry. I am a noob. Can you explain what you meant by check each property name ?

Comment: public string city { get; set; } in your Address class

Comment: Also, which version of ASP.NET MVC are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Each property on your json object your are passing must map to a property in your Adresss class

i.e.

```
public class Address
{
   public string address { get; set; }
   public string city { get; set; }
   // etc...
}
```

in your sample json data you say that you have address1, address2 that will not work, json object properties must match exactly.

Comment: I am using mvc3. this is what my address object looks like 

namespace PeopleSoftControlsPOC.Domain
{
    public class Address : IAddress
    {
        public string Address1 { get; set; }
        public string Address2 { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string Zip { get; set; }

    }
}